# how to cast timestamp to get hour HH format in spark scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a csv data file which contains a column of times in such format HH:MM:SS
I am trying to query the csv  using spark-sql in order to get the most busy and less busy hours of entrances/exits .
can anyone help me solve this problem ? much appreciated !

here is a sample of my csv file :

```
emp_name,emp_badge,door_number,date_time,usage_type
Capucine Letellier,28161comp,5,22:36:27,ENTRANCE
Zoé Bonnin de la Lenoir,75976comp,5,01:08:49,ENTRANCE
Henri Potier,66586comp,4,03:13:16,ENTRANCE
Théodore Rodriguez,39004comp,3,20:55:11,ENTRANCE
Christine Bonneau de Rodrigues,23965comp,4,18:45:42,EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

If your csv contains

1. string like "HH:MM:ss" then:

   ```
   val myCsv = spark.read.csv("path/to/csv")
   //this one splits you string by : and takes the first part of it
   val addHour = myCsv.withColumn("hour", split($"date_time", ":")(0))
   ```
2. timestamp format then:

   ```
   val myCsv = spark.read.csv("path/to/csv")
   //  Cast it first to timestamp because csv doesn't keep column format, after that format it to HH
   val addHour = myCsv.withColumn("hour", date_format($"date_time".cast("timestamp"), "HH"))
   ```

I hope this helped you.

Later edit:
To use $ operator for column you need to import spark implicits:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Now you can use $ instead of col("column_name") function.

Comment: In both cases it returns an error : value $ is not a member of StringContext.

Comment: Before that use:
    import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hour(string date)` function which returns the hour of the timestamp. Example: `hour('2009-07-30 12:58:59') = 12`, `hour('12:58:59') = 12`.

Next, you can calculate the busy hours and less busy hours like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val rawData = spark.read.csv("data.csv")

// Busy Hours calculation
val windowSpecBusyHours = Window.partitionBy("_c4").orderBy(col("transactions").desc)
val busyHours = rawData
  .withColumn("hours", hour(col("_c3")))
  .groupBy("_c4", "hours").agg(count("*").alias("transactions"))
  .withColumn("dense_rank", dense_rank().over(windowSpecBusyHours))
  .select("_c4", "hours", "transactions").where(col("dense_rank") === 1)
busyHours.show(false)

// Less Busy Hours calculation
val windowSpecLessBusyHours = Window.partitionBy("_c4").orderBy(col("transactions").asc)
val lessBusyHours = rawData
  .withColumn("hours", hour(col("_c3")))
  .groupBy("_c4", "hours").agg(count("*").alias("transactions"))
  .withColumn("dense_rank", dense_rank().over(windowSpecLessBusyHours))
  .select("_c4", "hours", "transactions").where(col("dense_rank") === 1)
lessBusyHours.show(false)
```

Comment: thank you sir ! it works like magic , but can you reference a link for the usage of window + orderby/partition by . seems of interesting usage !

Comment: Sure, you can checkout the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html. Also there are some examples here too: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html